# Bootstrap search suggestion as user types

Tags: html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Spotify API's search endpoint to give the user a suggestion of the artist he's looking for as he types. Ex: he types 'em' on the search box, I'd like to take whatever first entry matches 'em' from the Spotify request and then print the rest in the search box with a light font weight. In this case, when typing "em", I'd like for it to show "eminem" in the search box.

The code I have so far:

```
$( "#name" ).keyup(makeAjaxRequest);

function makeAjaxRequest() {
  if($('input#name').val().length > 2) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
      data: {q: $('input#name').val()},
      type: 'get',
      success: function(response) {
        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Example of the JSON I'm working with: 
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=em*&type=artist
Thank you very much!

Comment: what's the response value?

Comment: Response value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way of achieving this is the [Autocomplete plugin](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Hmm interesting, is there a way to remove the list that shows beneath the search box and put the first suggestion in that list as text in the search box? thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I don't think that would be good UX. Unfortunately I'm not at computer anymore, so I can't look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the info!